# How to make an Expandable TableView with Profile Img?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I was trying to create a Slide side out menu using the [SWRevealViewController](http://www.appcoda.com/sidebar-menu-swift/?utm_source=sendy&utm_medium=email) but I could not do the expandable TableView and the profile with image + Hello, Name...

[image: what i need]

And all I could do was:

[image: what i already done]

Basically how do you make an expandable TableView and the profile.

Are there any examples of how to do this?

Comment: You'll need to write your own code for that. As far as I know there isn't a 'read-to-go' library for it.

Comment: I'm beginner so I do not know very well where to start, you have any idea where to start?

Comment: do it on your own with ContainerView/ChildViewControllers with custom delegates this gives you more flexibility then any other libs.

Comment: @Gabriel Rodrigues Its actually allot easier than you think. The solution I posted was what a friend of mine that works at Apple recommended I do when I ran into this problem a few months ago. You just have to organize your data intelligently and then make sure any changes you make to the data source match what changes you made to the tableView insert methods or you'll cause errors.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Could I suggest renaming the post to: How to make a Expandable Table View? it seems you understand the slide out part, and it just complicates the question, you might get more traffic the other way and better help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From what I can tell, you want an expandable table view, **ie**: *Click a row in the table, and more options will appear.*

I've achieved that in the past using the following:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? OuterCell{

        if let object = data[indexPath.row] as? OuterObject{
            if(object.open == false){
                data.insert(InnerObject(content: object.innerContent), atIndex: indexPath.row + 1)
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Left)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }else{
                data.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row + 1)
                tableView.beginUpdates()
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Left)
                tableView.endUpdates()
            }
            object.open = !object.open
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what is happening here is the `dataSource` for the TableView is represented by the `data` array in this example. This is what you connect to all the `TableViewDelegate` hooks.

Within the data array I am holding two types of objects, a *OuterObject* and an *InnerObject*.

The *OuterObject* contains all the information for the inner objects that it contains, and if you click on it, it will dynamically add its children into the data array.

**Example Data** (I'm using JSON cause its easy to read and understand, you'll have to represent this in swift)

```
[
{
  name="Ensino",
  type="outerObject",
  open=true
  childObjects=[
    {
      name="Servico",
      type="innerObject"
    },
    {
      name="Avaliacao",
      type="innerObject"
    }
  ]
},
{
  name="Pesquisa",
  type="outerObject",
  open=false
  childObjects=[]
}
]
```

So in your case you would need an "Ensino" object, with a children property containing data for: Avaliaco, Servicos, ect...

Outer Object also keeps state as to whether or not it is open or closed, that way if you click on it again, you can know to remove all the inner objects that belong to it.

In this example I have hardcoded the OuterObject to always have at most one child, you would have to modify the code to be smarter as to how many objects are inserted/deleted upon click to be based on how many children objects the outer object you click has.

By calling `tableView.beginUpdates()`, `tableView.beginUpdates()`, `tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths()` you are accessing the methods that will allow an animated transition to happen when you update the data.

The key to solving this problem is creating an intelligent data source, and then leveraging the methods that Apple has in `UITableView` to make it happen.

Let me know if you need more help, this is an advanced `TableView` topic.

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues Did you try my solution and was it able to help?

Answer (score 1):

check this sample code [dropdown menu](https://github.com/BijeshNair/NIDropDown.git)

this might give you some idea.

Comment: people say should be done with expandable table like this: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/jkexpandtableview

Comment: @GabrielRodrigues yes, it's all about animation, but you have to implement those stuff yourself :)

Comment: If you use the tableView methods I described in my solution you get the iOS animation for free, you can even customize which animation is used by controlling the `withRowAnimation` property on the insert/remove method. I believe the options are left, right, fade